# Strange behaviour of HtmlHelper when partial view shares model with parent view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I do have a workaround for this issue, but it's so strange that I'd really like to understand the underlying cause.

I'm using ASP.NET's MVC with razor, and one of the pages I have on my site is a private message view. This shows a private message from another user, and at the bottom has a quick reply form which lives in a partial view. I think it'd clutter the question up too much with irrelevant details to give even a skeletal version of the code, so I'll just list the key bits:

- `MessageModel` - The view model for a message, used both for viewing an existing message and for submitting a new one
- `MessageController` - Like it sounds, the controller class for private message stuff, including:

  - `Message` - The action for viewing a message you've received.
  - `Compose` - The action for handling new POSTed messages
  - `QuickReply` - The action for a partial _QuickReply view.
- The `Message` view, and `_QuickReply` partial view.

Both the `Message` and `QuickReply` views have a `MessageModel` as their view model, and `Compose` takes one as a parameter.

So the `Message` view includes the following line to render the `_QuickReply` partial:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("QuickReply", new { recipient = Model.SenderUsername, subject = Model.Subject })};
```

And `_QuickReply` contains (along with other things) the following:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Subject)
```

Finally, the `QuickReply` action method prepends "RE:" to the beginning of the subject it's passed before putting that in the `MessageModel` it passes to its partial view.

So, finally we get to the strange part: The hidden tag rendered in the partial view by the `HtmlHelper` contains the *original* subject from the `Message` view's `MessageModel`, without the prepended 'RE:'.

What makes it particularly strange is the workaround. I changed the name of the parameter in the `QuickReply` method from `subject` to `originalSubject` and made the same change in the call from the `Message` view:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("QuickReply", new { recipient = Model.SenderUsername, originalSubject = Model.Subject })};
```

And now... it works! The hidden tag contains the version with the 'RE:' prefix.

I stuck a break point in the partial view, and confirmed that the `HtmlHelper.ViewData.Model` contains the correct version, with the prefix, whether or not I apply the workaround. So I'm completely mystified as to why it then goes and renders the version with its parent's model instead, or what the Action method's parameter names should have to do with anything.

Can anyone shed any light? As I said, I'm not looking for workarounds or fixes as I already have one I'm fine with, I'd just like to understand the behaviour. Let me know if you have trouble reproducing this and I can try to come up with a brief-as-possible full example that demonstrates it.

Comment: I have trouble reproducing. Can you post a sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your QuickReply controller action, try adding ModelState.Clear() before returning your ActionResult.  It seems MVC is caching the original model state.